# Admin site is not working and throwing Error about one of the views but views are still working django

Tags: python, django, web, django-admin

[This is the Error it is throwing Plz check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rteV.png)

[I am trying to get the posts related to certain tag and I did that but when I accessing admin panel it is showing on posts_tag view, I am not able to debug that why it is related to admin panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2N8e.png)

```
    class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tag',through='Tagged')
    class Meta:
        ordering=['-date_posted']
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail',kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
`class Tag(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    posts = models.ManyToManyField('Post',through='Tagged')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
class Tagged(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

## urls.py

```
urlpatterns=[
path('',views.post_list,name='blog-home'),
path('<tag>/',views.post_tag,name='blog-tag'),
path('post/<int:pk>/',views.post_detail,name='post-detail'),
path('post/new/',views.post_create,name='post-create'),
path('post/<int:pk>/update/',views.post_update,name='post-update'),
path('post/<int:pk>/delete/',views.post_delete,name='post-delete'),
path('about/',views.about,name='blog-about')]
```

## views.py

```
def post_tag(request,tag):
    t=Tag.objects.get(name=tag).posts.all()
    tags = Tagged.objects.all()
    return render(request,'blog/home.html',context={'posts':posts,'tags':tags})`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you are trying to use `admin url` but you are not providing `admin url` in your `urls.py`

If you want to use `admin url` then you should provide `admin url` in your `urls.py` as below...

```
path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
```

In your case what actually doing is you did not provide admin url but still you are trying to `localhost:8000/admin/` So, it will call below url from your urls.py

```
path('<tag>/',views.post_tag,name='blog-tag')
```

Because, as per your logic if you are providing any word after `localhost:8000` it will catch as `<tag>` and calling `views.post_tag` and as per your logic in `post_tag view` you will get `admin` as `tag` name and find it in `Tag model` but in your tag model there were no any tag named as admin so it is throwing error like... `Tag matching query is does not exist`

Answer (score 0):

In your `settings.py` file make sure that `ROOT_URLCONF` points to your main urlpatterns file (a `urls.py` file), and add the line `path('admin/', admin.site.urls)` to the patterns.

```
urlpatterns=[
    # This line should point correctly to the admin site (/admin)
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    path('',views.post_list,name='blog-home'),
    path('<tag>/',views.post_tag,name='blog-tag'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/',views.post_detail,name='post-detail'),
    path('post/new/',views.post_create,name='post-create'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/update/',views.post_update,name='post-update'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/delete/',views.post_delete,name='post-delete'),
    path('about/',views.about,name='blog-about')]
```

Because, Django doesn't implement the admin site by default and if you don't implement the url pattern no admin site will be found and you will get an error like that.